# Do I still need to declare the instance variable if I am using @property?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios5, properties

In Objective C you can now use @property and @synthesize to auto generate get and set methods. My question is: Do I still need to declare the property in the interface? My program compiles and runs fine without it. But most books and other examples still have it. Why?

```
@interface Person : NSObject {
// do i need the declaration "NSString name;"? why?
// i have notice that my program works fine without it.
// but many programming examples still incude it.     
// NSString name;
}
@property NSString *name;
@end

@implementation Person
@synthesize name;
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're talking about is the ivar. You do not need to declare it as the `@synthesize` adds it for you. This did not use to be the case on older compilers (and obviously before `@propertiy` was added to the language), thus a lot of people and books still do.

PS: You also do not need the `{...}` if you don't have any ivars, e.g.:

```
@interface Person : NSObject

@property NSString *name;
//...
```

Answer (score 3):

This depends on runtime. Modern runtime is used in iOS and you don't have to declade ivars. This is not always the case in OS X though. See here - http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtVersionsPlatforms.html

Comment: i thought this was a compiler thing and would not affect runtime.

Comment: compiler just knows what runtime it compiles for

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to; the ivar will be generated for you.  But the debugger won't show you auto-generated ivars, so I like to declare them anyways.

Comment: that's good to know, but a pain. the whole point is to eliminate unnecessary typing.

Comment: i can see the ivars and their values just like everything else in the debugger on xcode 4.2.1 on lion.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare the ivar.  The `@synthesize` directive does it for you if you omit the ivar.

Comment: The question is tagged iOS5.  It's always true if you're targeting iOS5.

Comment: Indeed, but a qualifier would be good so that Mac developers looking for info don't misread it.