# Is declaration of variable necessary in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In the following code:

```
       @interface UnitConverterViewController : UIViewController {
          UITextField     *tempText;
       }
       @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultLabel;
       @end
```

I've seen the same result achieved with out having

```
       {
          UITextField     *tempText;
       }
```

So, is this really necessary?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I still need to declare the instance variable if I am using @property?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459987/do-i-still-need-to-declare-the-instance-variable-if-i-am-using-property)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it's not necessary as of `Objective-c 2.0`.

see: [Do declared properties require a corresponding instance variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074248/properties-and-instance-variables-in-objective-c-2-0)

Comment: Yup np. This allows imo cleaner interface declarations.